# C# : how to track Upload and Download Baytes?

Tags: c#

i want to make a small windows app that start every windows startup this app can track downloads and uploads bytes daily , so how to do that using c# .

i am new to c#

**Edit :** download and upload bytes are what i upload to the internet and download from the internet using any internet connection , they are the same as sent and receive bytes in connection status window

thanks

Comment: Define "upload and download" bytes: do you mean on a specific NIC (then use WMI), if you mean through a cable/ADSL router then it depends on that router (SNMP *might* be an option). Getting the basic data in an API is the hard part, the C# coding will completely depend on solving that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look into the following for network related stuffs in .NET 
http://nayyeri.net/how-to-calculate-network-utilization-in-net

Hope it helps!